# R GAM interaction code suddenly stopped working

Tags: r, interaction, gam

This is really weird and I can not figure out a solution. I was running a GAM interaction code like this about the months ago. I've installed mgcv and gamair packages for GAM. It was just working fine with no errors.

```
Model1 <- gam(response ~ Location + s(predictor1) + s(predctor2, by = Location, m=1) + s(predictor3), data=Data, method = "REML", bs='cr', family=Gamma(link=identity))
```

Then, suddenly, the same code stopped working. I did some tests and found that the `by=` term was the issue. The output returns this error message:

```
'Error in smoothCon(split$smooth.spec[[i]], data, knots, absorb.cons, scale.penalty = scale.penalty, : Can't find by variable".
```

If I remove the `by=`, the code works fine. Even with only one predictor, if I add `by=`, the model doesn't work.

I did RStudio update, package updates, virus check, and everything. I have no idea why the same code with the same data suddenly stopped working. Any advice? Thank you.

Comment: It may well be relevant which package your function `gam()` is from, there's one in `mgcv` and another in package `gam`. `gam::s()` doesn't have an argument called 'by', but `mgcv::s()` can.

Comment: I assume `Location` is in the `Data` data frame?

Comment: Sorry, I'm using mgcv and gamair. Just now, I ran a sample code with by= in the mgcv manual. But it didn't work either ..

Comment: And yes, 'Location' is the data column name in the dataset (data frame).